# How can I install a specific version of Android on my phone for testing?

Tags: android

My boss recently gave me an HTC Wildfire phone for doing an Android version of one of our mobile apps, which is all fine and good, except that the app requires API level 8 (ie Android 2.2), and the phone itself only has Android 2.1 installed.  After much googling, I discovered that this phone does support Android 2.2, and carriers will be rolling out updates over the air for this model phone "in the near future".

Since I'm not entirely certain what our lazy carrier's definition of "near future" is, it would be nice if I could download images for particular releases and install them on my phone.  Coming from the world of the iPhone, it seems that this should be something rather necessary in order to successfully develop an Android app.

Yet, it doesn't seem that Google offers any Android OS updates themselves.  Have I no choice but to wait for the carrier to release an update?

**Edit**: Thanks for the suggestions regarding the emulator, but I'm asking about testing on hardware *only*.  I already have a working 2.2 emulator image, but I need to test on hardware now, since the emulator does a very poor job of things like video playback and audio processing.

Comment: Does it make sense to develop applications for API level 8 only? There aren't too many devices with official Froyo support and actually Froyo didn't add too many functionalities from developer point of view.

Comment: Yes, we need API support because our app requires the improvements in the audio/video packages, since it's very multimedia-oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you can test your application on Android 2.2:

1) You can use the [Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) provided by Google in the SDK. It is possible to create a virtual machine of any version of Android with various hardware options. However, the emulator does have some limitations such as not supporting certain hardware options (such as bluetooth) and it's also dreadfully slow to boot.

2) If you have to use an actual phone with 2.2, you can root your phone and flash a custom ROM. I'm not particularly familiar with how to root the Wildfire, or what custom ROMs are available for that specific phone, but [Cyanogen Mod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) has pretty good ROM support for HTC phones, as well as an active forum with tutorials.

Comment: Working with multimedia on the emulator will be really sluggish. 2) is probably the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to download images before OTA. You could check CyanogemMod from time to time - they're working on Wildfire support. Also you could use an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to bounce around with newer versions, I recommend the Nexus One as a dev phone if you can get your hands on one. Or, if you can deal with the constraints, start with a built-in AVD emulator with API 8 until your phone gets the OTA update.

Comment: Sadly, the Nexus One isn't available in my country. =/

Comment: Is the HTC Desire available in your country? That has 2.2 as well already.

Answer (score 0):

The Motorola Droid is also getting/has 2.2 on it.  At least in the States, in seems that most of the phones on Verizon already have it (non-scientific, just from talking to people I know).  So if that phone is available, it may be a decent choice.